# Is this picture of a man in Colorado Springs nearly being blown away, genuine, or a hoax?

Tags: united-states, weather, photography

This photo was shared on my Facebook page.

[image: Colorado Springs off Cimarron and I-25, this city worker is doing his best not to get swept up by the wind!]

The post was from FOX21 News Facebook News Feed (January 9 2017, 5:20pm): [Colorado Springs off Cimarron and I-25, this city worker is doing his best not to get swept up by the wind!](https://www.facebook.com/FOX21NewsColorado/photos/a.291830687608.119676.228459267608/10153649885702609/)

I wouldn't be surprised to find this is a hoax. Their left hand looks like it is pushing against the truck (supporting their weight), rather than stretched to hold on. Their right foot looks like it could be resting on top of the wood. The debris below looks like it is just sitting there. How is the person taking the picture able to do so while experiencing the same strong wind?

Comment: It's been windy in Colorado, but not that windy (notice the trees are still standing, the angles of the stoplights, the pieces of wood on the ground that are not blowing away). I'm sure you're correct that he's just holding himself up like that.

Comment: He wouldn't even need to hold himself up (though that's definitely possible with practise and/or natural skill). Simply jumping and having the picture taken at hang-time would give the effect.

Comment: You can also notice his jacket is just hanging, not stretched in the supposed direction of wind.

Comment: Also, look at the chains dangling below his right hand.  If the wind is strong enough to pick up a human, those chains would be horizontal.

Comment: A joke doesn't mean "hoax". Seriously, it's a joke.

Comment: You can clearly see by the shape of the palm that the bottom hand is being used to adjust for the rotational force by his body pushing down and not holding on like his top hand

Comment: @fredsbend - It's one thing to post a picture on your own social media page as a joke. But, it's a totally different matter to send the picture to a tv news station and lie about the actual circumstances. Perhaps "hoax" is too strong to describe this, but "joke" is not strong enough. But, in any event, it is a fun and entertaining photo.

Comment: @KevinFegan I disagree: "hoax" is exactly the right word when you attempt to fool people.

Answer (score 9):

The Facebook post cites Cody Pierce as the source for the photo. In [a comment on that post](https://www.facebook.com/FOX21NewsColorado/photos/a.291830687608.119676.228459267608/10153649885702609/?type=3&comment_id=10153649910982609&reply_comment_id=10153649936647609&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R9%22%7D) (does that link to the comment? it should) he states:

> Marg Braddock Real or photo chopped? Either way it is an impressive picture!
>
> 17 · January 10 at 6:48pm · Edited
>
> Cody Pierce It's real just holding him self up
>
> 24 · January 9 at 4:09pm

So the photo is a real photo. The guy is just holding himself up.

Yes, it's possible that this is not the real Cody Pierce, or a different one, or he's lying. But that seems to be evidence enough.

Comment: Yes, it does link directly to that comment. Thanks.

Comment: Also if the wind was that strong there wouldn't be random junk on the ground just laying there not moved an inch by the wind.